# How to fully build with Rubber?

Tags: compiling, rubber

How do I do a full build with [`rubber`](https://launchpad.net/rubber/) that does the equivalent of

```
latex foo
bibtex foo
makeindex -s myindex.ist foo
latex foo
latex foo
dvips foo
ps2pdf foo
```

The files I am using are

```
foo.tex
myindex.ist
```

Comment: Just curious; what are the advantages of Rubber over latexmk? I do it all manually, but I'm interested anyway.

Comment: `rubber --ps --pdf foo.tex` is not enough? (`man rubber`)

Comment: Just complementing @eudoxos' comment, to properly set the index style, you can add information for `rubber` in the comments of your `foo.tex` file, in the form of directives. A `rubber` directive goes like this: `% rubber: cmd args`. In your case, add the following line to your `tex` file: `% rubber: index.style myindex.ist`. If you use the `makeidx` package, add `% rubber: makeidx.style myindex.ist` instead. There are several directives in which you can set `rubber`'s behaviour. `man` pages and also `info rubber` are your friends. Hope it helps. `:)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's consider the `foo.tex` file. Running

```
rubber --ps --pdf foo
```

will correctly produce both `ps` and `pdf` outputs. The flags are:

- `--ps`: process the DVI produced by the process through `dvips` to produce a PostScript document. According to the manual, **order matters**, so it cannot come after the `--pdf` flag.
- `--pdf`: produce PDF output. When this option comes after `--ps`, it will use `ps2pdf` instead of `pdftex`.

`rubber` will automatically run `makeindex` for you, but in this case, you want to provide a specific style. In order to properly set the index style for `makeindex`, you need to add information for `rubber` in the comments of your `foo.tex file`, in the form of directives.

A `rubber` directive goes like this:

```
% rubber: cmd args
```

According to the manual, we have a special directive to deal with index styles:

- `index.style <style>`: specifies the index style to be used. It's important to note that each of these directives may be used with an optional first argument of the form `(foo,bar,quux)` in order to specify that the directive only applies to the indexes named `foo`, `bar` and `quux`. By default, directives are applied to all indices.

In your case, considering the `myindex.ist` style, add the following line to the `foo.tex` file:

```
% rubber: index.style myindex.ist
\documentclass{book}
...
```

An important note from the manual:

- When using the package `makeidx` instead of  `index`, the directives must of course be prefixed by `makeidx.` instead of `index.`, and the optional first argument is not accepted.

So, if you use the `makeidx package`, add:

```
% rubber: makeidx.style myindex.ist
\documentclass{book}
...
```

instead.

There are several directives in which you can set `rubber`'s behaviour. `man` pages and also `info rubber` are your friends. I strongly recommend the reading. `:)`

<sub>**Disclaimer:** We had a new blog post about `rubber` ready to go, but unfortunately we had to postpone it due to some `css` issues. This question is a lucky coincidence. `:)`</sub>

Comment: How do I accept that the option ``-s``
``% Rubber-s makeidx.style indexstyle.ist``
It's not working: error: "unknown Directive-s"

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: Try to put this line `% rubber: makeidx.style indexstyle.ist` in the first line of your `tex` file. `:)`